# How to implement a responsive/performant filter (text entry) in dotnet Maui?

Tags: .net, filtering, maui

I'm implementing a Maui app, with an Entry control for filter text.
Whenever the text changes, I filter a list (ListView).
But the result is clumsy, typing is slow, as it has to wait for the filter operation to complete.

(Code samples simplified for brewity)

Entry control and ListView on my xaml page:

```
<Entry
    Placeholder="Start typing to filter the list"
    Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"
    TextChanged="FilterTextEntry_TextChanged"/>

<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
                    <Label x:Name="NameLabel"
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Event handler in code-behind

```
private void FilterTextEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _vm.ApplyFilter();
}
```

Refresh method in MyViewModel

```
public void ApplyFilter()
{
    foreach (var listItem in ListItems)
    {
        listItem.IsVisible = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterText)
            ? true
            : listItem.Name.Contains(TypedText);
    }
}
```

How can I improve the performance of the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I found this article: https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2018/08/24/xamarin-search-as-you-type-with-delay/ 
but it wasn't what I was looking for. It just delayed starting the search, but I always had to pause typing for the list to be filtered. There were some great ideas there though.

Also, it helped me clarify what I wanted: I actually needed to start a filter process, but break it if another character was added to the text and start over again.
So I learned a bit about cancellation tokens here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

and came up with something stupid simple.
Changed the filter method to be cancellable:

```
public void ApplyFilter(CancellationToken ct)
{
    foreach (var listItem in ListItems)
    {
        if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        listItem.IsVisible = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterText)
            ? true
            : listItem.Name.Contains(TypedText);
    }
}
```

... and changed the text changed event handler

```
private CancellationTokenSource _filterCancellationToken = null;

private async void FilterTextEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel the previous filter process and create a new cancellation token (CT).
    // A CT can't be used after cancellation has been requested,
    // so immediately create another.
    Interlocked.Exchange(
        ref _filterCancellationToken,
        new CancellationTokenSource())?.Cancel();

    // Start filtering and provide the newly re-created cancellation token
    await Task.Run(() => _vm.ApplyFilter(_filterCancellationToken.Token));
}
```

Now it's cool :-)

**Later edit**
I found that it works great in certain cases but it does not in others.
The case where it worked perfectly is with a ListView or a CollectionView wrapped in a ScrollView - and this is a setup that many articles suggest not to use. But removing the ScrollView wrapper simply killed filter performance in my case.

I also have a sorting feature on the same ListView/CollectionView. When the ScrollView wrapper is in place sorting performance is horrible. If I remove the ScrollView wrapper, it improves a bit (6 seconds vs 4 seconds for about 20 ViewCell items with one label and two buttons each).

I ended up preferring good filter performance so stayed with a CollectionView wrapped in a ScrollView and the cancellation logic above.